# Primefaces gmap component, fitBounds and update

Tags: google-maps, jsf, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 6.0. I am developing a Liferay portlet using version 6.2.6.

I need my maps to show all their markers so i used the `fit bounds = "true`. The problem is , if for any reason (ex. change the model with new overlays) i update the map two things may happen:

1) If i haven't specified a `center` and `zoom` attribute, the map isn't rendered at all. At the browser console the error `'too much recursion'` appears.

2) If i have the a `center` and `zoom` attributes specified, on the next update the map will not perform a `fitBounds`, and the maps center will be the one specified.

It is worth noting that on the first load of the page/portlet, whatever values i set to the attributes, the map will be "fitted". That means that pressing F5 to refresh the page displays the map correctly, but performing an ajax update result in the above behavior.

One workaround is to bind the center and zoom attributes to some managed bean properties, and use the `stateChange` event to store the initial state but unfortunately this doesn't fit my requirements.

The real question is: how can i have my gmap component "fitted" after every update. Is it possible out of the box, or are there any workarounds?

Sample code:

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton id="update-button" value="#{i18n['update']}" update=":map" />
</h:form>

<p:gmap id="map" center="( 12, 12)" zoom="8" type="ROADMAP" 
model="#{modelBean.mapModel}" fitBounds="true" />
```

Managed bean

```
  @ManagedBean
  @ViewScoped
  public class RoutesModelBean{
        private MapModel mapModel;
        private LatLng mapCenter;
    private Integer zoom;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        _LOGGER.info("inti");
        mapModel = new DefaultMapModel();

        //Shared coordinates
        LatLng coord1 = new LatLng(36.879466, 30.667648);
        LatLng coord2 = new LatLng(36.883707, 30.689216);
        LatLng coord3 = new LatLng(36.879703, 30.706707);
        LatLng coord4 = new LatLng(36.885233, 30.702323);

        //Basic marker
        mapModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord1, "Konyaalti"));
        mapModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord2, "Ataturk Parki"));
        mapModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord3, "Karaalioglu Parki"));
        mapModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord4, "Kaleici"));

    }

    //Getter setters

}
```

Comment: any solution on this?

Comment: Unfortunately not any i know of. It is probably a bug and not an expected behavior. I started using the native gmap javascript api to handle these things now. The only workaround i found is to re load the entire page entirely (via external context or facesRedirect=true), but of course then any view scoped managed bean will be reconstructed. So either you have to build stateless views or deal with it with via the native api.